# is there a way to limit the audit log amount of Hibernate envers?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am testing the functionality's of hibernate envers, I like the module but I don't want the audit tables to become too big. Can hibernate envers be configured in such a way that the audit table can never exceed a predefined number of audit rows?

Comment: No it is all or nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that Envers provides specifically.

What a lot of users tend to do is use the `ValidityAuditStrategy` and then specify a partition scheme on the database based on the `REVEND` and `REVEND_TSTMP` fields.

By doing that, you could setup a strategy where

- You store the more recent audit rows on faster disk medium.
- You archive off older audit rows based on the partition scheme.